# AngularJS $watch not updating my output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML which looks like -

```
<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="post in posts" style="list-style: none;">
        <li style="padding: 5px; background-color: #f5f5f5;">
            <h4>
                <a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">{{post.postTitle}}</a>
            </h4>
            <div class="post-details" ng-show="showDetails">
                <p>{{post.postContent}}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now the data is being populated from a JSON based REST URL and being displayed. I also have a form that will be adding new post to the database-

```
<form data-ng-submit="submit()"
        data-ng-controller="FormSubmitController">
        <h3>Add Post</h3>
        <p>
            Title: <input type="text" data-ng-model="postTitle">
        </p>
        <p>
            Content: <input type="text" data-ng-model="postContent">
        </p>
        <p>
            Tags: <input name="postTags" data-ng-model="postTags" ng-list
                required>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="loadPosts()" /><br>
    </form>
```

I basically want to achieve two things -
1. As soon as i add new post it shows up in the list of posts above.
2. As soon as i manually add a new post in the backend, front end automatically updates.

Is it possible to achieve both using angular and if yes how will i be able to do that.
Below is my controller code, which as of now is showing me existing posts as well as letting me add new post to DB.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

    app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/MyApp/posts')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.posts = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Error in fetching the JSON data.");
            });
            $scope.$watch('posts', function(newVal, oldVal){
                console.log('changed');
                alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
            }, true);
        /*$scope.$watch('posts', function() {
            alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
            console.log("test log");
            $scope.$digest();
        });*/
    });

    app.controller('FormSubmitController', [ '$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http) {

            $scope.loadPosts = function() {
                $http.get('http://localhost:8080/MyApp/posts')
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.posts = data;
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    //$scope.posts_updated = data;
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Error in fetching the JSON data.");
                });
            }

            $scope.list = [];

            $scope.submit = function() {

                var formData = {
                    "postTitle" : $scope.postTitle,
                    "postContent" : $scope.postContent,
                    "postTags" : $scope.postTags,
                    "postedBy" : "admin"
                };

                var response = $http.post('addPost', formData);
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("na");
                });
                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({
                        data : data
                    }));
                });

                //Empty list data after process
                $scope.list = [];

            };
        } ]);
</script>
```

Any help on this will be really appreciable.

Comment: So it is not showing nothing, even after page loads initially, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: on your success of post, you can just push the added object into your posts list. This will trigger the two-way-binding, and the object will "automatically" appear in your ng-repeater.

```
$scope.posts.push(element);
```

2: This one is a bit tricky, since angular is a client-side application, it doesn't recognize what happens on the server-side. What you have to do to make this work is to look at websockets (like SignalR or similar) that can make a push to your client whenever something gets added. This also depends on that your "manual" insert is done using a programatically method. Doing it directly from database-changes is going to be alot more painfull

Comment: Created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zL48by4r/

It still is not working for you, so not sure if i have been able to hit the code correctly.

Comment: hehe, i can see the error now. Youre using two different controllers, that will have to different scope. $scope.posts in each controller will be different. If you try to push it to $rootScope.posts instead, it should work

Comment: :) i was about to post the same. It seems the issue is with two controllers only. thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zL48by4r/3/ i bypassed the post, since it didn't work in the fiddle, but you get the picture:)

Comment: ohh wow, let me just try it and in case it worked, you are indeed a saviour for me.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/68215604 if you are new to angular, i recommend you watch this one. It explains some good stuff the kamikaze way! good luck!

Comment: ya sure will do that, but somehow i am still stuck with the same problem. its not getting updated :(

Comment: Strange as soon as i replace my actual web service URL this problem comes, if i go with invalid URL where the DB data is not being fetched its working fine

Comment: You might try to put the push within a $scope.$apply(function(){ dothepush here }); how does the data object returned from the service look?

Comment: If youre still stuck, please add a new fiddler, and i'll take a look at it again.

Comment: ok for the time being i have handled the issue in hand with single controller and rest as suggested by you. its working fine. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize $scope.posts before invoking $http request

   $scope.posts = [];
2. Since you are using $http service, it should automatically repaint ng-repeat when new data found. So you don't need be to worried about it
3. Very important thing is that you don't need to call $digest when you use $http service. Using $digest blindly is a very bad practice and is major performance issue. In the end of $http service angular automatically call $digest so you don't need to call again

Comment: Well, http will for sure not automatically detect changes done in the backend, lets say the database except for when you activally poll it from the client or doing push from the backend

Comment: not helping, in my code where new post is being added to the DB i am writing $scope.posts[]; however even then my ng-repeat is not getting the new entry into its list. Do i need to have $scope.$watch or not?

Comment: @thsorens, If you use $http service, you don't to call $digest. It will be automatically invoked $digest.  Have you seen angular $http service code yet? Please have a look

Comment: @AJ84 if you use $scope.posts in ng-repeat,, why do you need to watch it again? Whats the hell ng-repeat do then? Please check ng-repeat code in angularjs. There is already a $watch set inside ng-repeat. Invoking $digest or $apply in the controller is the worst case and I believe you have lost your control in your code then.  Angularjs suggest only to call $digest  when you change scope out of angular context

Comment: @SamirDas: you are correct on the $digest. My bad. Just havent done angular in a while:)

Comment: Thanks samir for the insights. any good suggestion on angularJS. i am making a micro blog (mobile friendly) using Angular and Mongo with Spring REST. Any good resource will be really helpful.